# How many mipmaps does a texture have in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, textures, pyopengl, mipmaps

Nevermind that I'm the one who created the texture in the first place and I should know perfectly well how many mipmaps I loaded/generated for it. I'm doing this for a unit test. There doesn't seem to be a `glGetTexParameter` parameter to find this out. The closest I've come is something like this:

```
int max_level;
glGetTexParameter( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, &max_level );
int max_mipmap = -1;
for ( int i = 0; i < max_level; ++i )
{
    int width;
    glGetTexLevelParameter( GL_TEXTURE_2D, i, GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH, &width );
    if ( 0 == width )
    {
        max_mipmap = i-1;
        break;
    }
)
```

Anyhow, `glGetTexLevelParameter()` will return 0 width for a nonexistent mipmap if I'm using an NVidia GPU, but with Mesa, it returns `GL_INVALID_VALUE`, which leads me to believe that this is very much the *Wrong Thing To Do*.

How do I find out which mipmap levels I've populated a texture with?

Comment: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/621709-query-number-of-mipmap-levels/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The spec is kinda fuzzy on this. It says that you will get `GL_INVALID_VALUE` if the level parameter is "larger than the maximum allowable level-of-detail". Exactly how this is defined is not stated.

The [documentation for the function](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetTexLevelParameter) clears it up a bit, saying that it is the maximum possible number of LODs for the largest possible texture (`GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE`). Other similar functions like the [`glFramebufferTexture`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glFramebufferTexture) family explicitly state this as the limit for `GL_INVALID_VALUE`. So I would expect that.

Therefore, Mesa has a bug. However, you could work around this by assuming that either 0 or a `GL_INVALID_VALUE` error means you've walked off the end of the mipmap array.

That being said, I would suggest employing [`glTexStorage`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glTexStorage2D) and never having to even ask the question again. This will forcibly prevent someone from setting MAX_LEVEL to a value that's too large. It's pretty new, from GL 4.2, but it's implemented (or will be very soon) across all non-Intel hardware that's still being supported.

Answer (score 13):

It looks like there is currently no way to query how many mipmap levels a texture has, short of the OPs trial/error with @NicolBolas' invalid value check. For most cases I guess its performance wouldn't matter if the level 0 size doesn't change often.

However, assuming the texture does not have a [limited number of levels](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/621709-query-number-of-mipmap-levels/), the specs give the preferred calculation (note the use of `floor`, and *not* `ceiling` as some examples give):

```
numLevels = 1 + floor(log2(max(w, h, d)))
```

> 6. What is the dimension reduction rule for each successively smaller mipmap level?
>
>    Each successively smaller mipmap level is half the size of the previous level, but if this half value is a fractional value, you should round down to the next largest integer.
>      ...
>      Note that this extension is compatible with supporting other rules because it merely relaxes the error and completeness conditions for mipmaps.  At the same time, it makes sense to provide developers a single consistent rule since developers are unlikely to want to generate mipmaps for different rules unnecessarily.  One reasonable rule is sufficient and preferable, and the "floor" convention is the best choice.
>
>    [[ARB_texture_non_power_of_two]](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_non_power_of_two.txt)

This can of course be verified with the OPs method, or in my case when I received a `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT` with `glFramebufferTexture2D(..., numLevels)`.

Comment: For reference, the formula is given in glspec46, §8.14.3 _Mipmapping_. (The same formula is present in earlier specs in §3.8, down to OpenGL 2.0, where NPOT textures appear.)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're building mipmaps in a standard way, the number of unique images will be something like ceil(log_2(max(width,height)))+1.  This can be easily derived by noticing that mipmaps reduce image size by a factor of two each time until there is a single pixel.

Comment: come on, give the guy some slack. we don't have to get everything right before it's even written. a test case will allow to adjust the formula.